# CloudFront not caching API Gateway response

Tags: caching, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

Using this architecture to serve images:

`CloudFront(caching) > API Gateway rest api (catch all paths route) > Lambda (resizing) > S3`

The **Lambda** is using `sharp` to resize the image to a `png` and is forwarding the following headers from S3: ETag, ContentLength and LastModified, the response is base64 encoded.

Here are the headers from said CloudFront(on the right) and another CloudFront that directly loads from S3(on the left):
[image]